# video not playing on Android (chrome) and iOS (safari)

Tags: android, ios, ffmpeg, mp4

Hi I have a few video that **DOES NOT** play in Android (directly on Chrome) and on iOS (directly on Safari) but plays on Windows, Mac and Linux on any browser.

Here is the `ffprobe` output

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'intro_sequence_01.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    date            : 2018-10-08T08:15:57.948731
    encoder         : Lavf58.18.104
  Duration: 00:00:08.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 259 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High 4:4:4 Predictive) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv444p, 1920x1080, 257 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
```

and here is the ffprobe output of another video that **DOES** play on Android and Chrome:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'Torcia_960x540.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42mp41
    creation_time   : 2017-02-10T16:14:10.000000Z
  Duration: 00:00:11.52, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 10585 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv), 960x540 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 10576 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25k tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-02-10T16:14:10.000000Z
      handler_name    : Mainconcept MP4 Video Media Handler
      encoder         : AVC Coding
```

Both are .mp4 format and are using `h264` codec.
As far as I can see, I notice a difference in codec profile `h264 (High 4:4:4 Predictive)` vs `Video: h264 (Main)` and `yuv444p` vs `yuv420p(tv)` and on metadata section.

I tried re-encoding the first video with ffmpeg but without success.
Does anyone know why video1 is not compatible with Android and iOS and how to re-ffmpeg it to make it play?
Thanks!

Comment: The devices don't support the `Hi444PP` profile. What's the `ffmpeg` command you used to re-encode?

Comment: @aergistal: Thanks! I have reencoded like that `ffmpeg -i original.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -acodec copy -vprofile main -pix_fmt yuv420p reencoded.mp4` and now it plays! Thanks again! If you turn your comment into an answer I'll vote and accept it.

Comment: Did the codec really work in Safari on OS X?

Comment: In one case I had to change the video codec from `libx264` to `mpeg4`, using `-vcodec mpeg4`, because some Android devices don't support H.264.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to aeristal comment on my question above, I have re-encoded my video like this:

```
ffmpeg -i original.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -acodec copy -vprofile main -pix_fmt yuv420p reencoded.mp4
```

and now it plays back on Android and iOS too.

The key switches are `-vprofile main` and most important `-pix_fmt yuv420p` as Android / iOS does not support `Hi444PP` profile as stated by aergistal